# 'createLabeledTextarea' is not a function error when compiling to DLL

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm attempting to create a plugin with a form context balloon that renders a textarea input instead of a regular text input. I'm using the `createLabeledTextarea` helper function (instead of `createLabeledInputText`). This works fine when compiling from source using the plugin development environment (`npm run start`). However, when I compile the DLL (`npm run dll:build`), I get an error saying `createLabeledTextarea` is not a function. According to the documentation, this helper should work the same way as `createLabeledTextInput`.

Here is my code:

```
_createTextarea( label ) {
    const labeledTextarea = new LabeledFieldView( this.locale, createLabeledTextarea );

    labeledTextarea.label = label;

    labeledTextarea.fieldView.set( {
        placeholder: 'Enter your annotation here...',
        minRows: 5,
        maxRows: 10,
    } );

    return labeledTextarea;
}
```

But again, once compiled to the DLL, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not a function
```

`t` being the `createLabeledTextarea` passed to `LabeledFieldView`.